# Header Wrapper has a gap below header inner

Tags: css, padding

I have 2 divs on my page(under construction).

One is the header_Wrapper which is page `width(100%)` and `header_inner(width: 980px)`
I added a navigation bar and now there is a gap(it looks like padding is set to the wrapper but there isn't.)

I have no idea how to fix this gap.
It appears in all the browsers I tested it in.
Chrome, Opera, FF, IE, Safari

I have added my code to a Jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/FRp7d/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this on the fiddle and it worked.

In .headerWrapper{}  add    height:36px;

In .headerInner{}  add     height:100%;

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Works great. It actually gives me an idea of what went wrong. When I hover over "navigation" and the background changes color I can see where the link height is different. Now all I have to do is fix that and it will be perfect. I checked in all 5 major browsers. Thanks :)

Comment: That you did. I tried the height of 36px on the wrapper earlier and like a beginner I forgot to add a height to my inner not thinking clearly.

Comment: I fixed the other part of the issue :)
I added a 20px height to the links and since they had a padding of 8px on top and bottom they became 36px in height filling all gaps and giving a seamless look.

Answer (score 0):

give padding 0 to clicker class.

Comment: Tried it.
I tried .clicker { padding: 0; } and when that failed I tried .clicker { padding: 0!important; }

Comment: Ah it appears I mispelled important in my CSS but when I corrected myself and the padding went away it got very messy.